# Code for diameter of generic tree not working when required to find out diameter of binary tree

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

Few days ago I was learning about generic trees , and I came across a code for the diameter of a generic tree as follows :

```
 static int diameter = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
  public static int findDia(Node node){
      int dch = -1; // dch = deepest child height
      int sdch =-1; // sdch = second deepest child height
      
      for(Node child : node.children){ // children of current node are in an arraylist , every node has data + reference of arraylist of its children
          int ch = findDia(child); // ch = child height
          if(ch>dch){
              sdch=dch;
              dch=ch;
          }else if(ch>sdch){
              sdch=ch;
          }
      }
      if(sdch+dch+2>diameter){
          diameter = sdch+dch+2;
      }
      return dch+1;
  }
```

Today when I was studying binary trees , I came across a similar question i.e. find diameter in a binary tree , but the solution given for the binary tree diameter question is different from this approach , is there a way to tweak this code so that it works for binary tree too? I have been trying to tweak it so that it works for binary tree but every time my code fails some test case . I have not put my binary tree code here because I have written multiple approaches but all of them fail some test case .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Binary tree is the *specialized version* of the General tree<sup>*[1]*</sup>, so any read-only algorithm that works on a General tree will work on a Binary tree too.

Since finding the diameter is a read-only operation, the algorithm should work pretty much unchanged.

Only difference is that a General tree has a list of children, while a Binary tree has just 2 separate child references, but that is a minor detail that the code should easily adapt to.

You could e.g. enhance a Binary tree `Node` class with a method to make it look like a General tree node:

```java
Node[] getChildren() {
    if (this.left == null) {
        if (this.right == null)
            return new Node[0];
        return new Node[] { this.right };
    }
    if (this.right == null)
        return new Node[] { this.left };
    return new Node[] { this.left, this.right };
}
```

Now replace `node.children` with `node.getChildren()` in the code and you're done.

<sup>***Reference 1:** [Difference between General tree and Binary tree](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-general-tree-and-binary-tree/)*</sup>